# Change the base color font from stripe CardNumberElement on Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stripe-payments

I'm personalizing the react stripe elements provided by Stripe, but I can't change the font color, the background is working and other styles, but the font color stays on black.

This is my stripe element:

```
<Grid item md={6}>
  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    required
    fullWidth
    className={classes.inputStyle}
    InputProps={{
      inputComponent: StripeInput,
      inputProps: {
        component: CardCvcElement
      },
      className: classes.multilineColor
    }}
    />
 </Grid>
```

It's styles:

```
inputFields: {
  borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
  backgroundColor: '#000000',
  color: '#FFF'
},
multilineColor: {
  color: '#FFFFFF'
},
```

The StripeInput component is this:

```
function StripeInput ({ component: Component, inputRef, ...props }) {
  const elementRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(inputRef, () => ({
    focus: () => elementRef.current.focus
  }));

  return (
    <Component
      onReady={element => (elementRef.current = element)}
      style={{
        base: {
          color: 'green' // The desired result is white, for the example I'm using green but no changes
        }
      }}
      {...props}/>
  )
}

export default StripeInput;
```

The normal text should be displayed with green or white color for example but this is the result:

[image]

The text always is displayed black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just fixed my issue with the font color, the fix was to add the styles to the Stripe Input component like this:

```
function StripeInput ({ component: Component, inputRef, ...props }) {
  const elementRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(inputRef, () => ({
    focus: () => elementRef.current.focus
  }));

  return (
    <Component
      onReady={element => (elementRef.current = element)}
      options={{
        style: {
          base: {
            color: '#FFF'
          }
        }
      }}
      {...props}/>
  )
}

export default StripeInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, thanks! To pass in options more dynamically, you can use the parent inputProps and it will get spread in Component with `...props`.

```
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    required
    fullWidth
    className={classes.inputStyle}
    InputProps={{
      inputComponent: StripeInput,
      inputProps: {
        component: CardCvcElement,
        options: { style: { base: { color: '#ffffff' }}},
      },
    }}
    />
```

Comment: That should work too